# 'Syntax error: invalid syntax' pointing to a while loop

Tags: python, pygame

The console I use, pycripter, says that the line with the `while` in it is incorrect. I checked my other programs and it works there.  Am I missing something? The error message says 'Syntax Error: invalid syntax'.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

Display = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 500))

SquareLocation((350, 100), (400,

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Please post the error you are getting.

Comment: Does it give any reason? It might be flagging the fact that it's a (seemingly) endless loop.

Comment: The problem is that previous line of code that has unclosed parentheses.

Comment: Please don't post incomplete code snippets without the error message next time and also don't post a screenshot of your code, since it can't be copied and pasted. Take a look at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the rest of the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: It seems that you code is incomplete.
Look:
    SquareLocation((350, 100), (400,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left the previous line (before the while statement) unfinished. There is no other problem with the code segment you provided.

Comment: WOW, I would have never thought of that, it worked. THANKS!

Comment: Yes, because you're allowed to continue a list/tuple on the next line, as long as you eventually have a closing ) or ]. So when the compiler gets to the line with the while statement, it has found new code but never got that closing bracket, so it throws an error.